# Installing C++ Boost library on different hard drive

Tags: c++, boost

I'm still pretty inexperienced with C++ but I need to install Boost 1.6.1.

I just want to do it with the minimum hassle possible.

I'm using visual studio 2015 for development, which is installed on my C drive. The problem is I don't have much space left on my C drive .

Is it possible to install boost on my D drive?

Can someone explain to me step by step how to so this or point me to a good step by step tutorial that explains how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: ***Is it possible to install boost on my D drive?*** Yes of course. I have boost installed multiple times (one for each configuration / several different compilers and 32 / 64 bit) on my X  drive. ***Can someone explain to me step by step how to so this*** I build boost from source using an out of source build so each install can share the same source.

Comment: Sorry, this question is too broad to be answered and/or asking for tutorials is off-topic. There are some tutorials on the Boost docs you should have a look at.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download my [Boost Build Environment](https://www.dropbox.com/s/41rbp4d066ve5zt/boost_build_environment.zip?dl=0).
2. Extract it to the root of your D drive. It will create a boost_build_environment directory.
3. Open the **MSBuild Command Prompt for VS2015**.
4. CD into D:\boost_build_environment.
5. Build boost as follows.

   msbuild /nologo /target:BuildAll BuildBoost.proj
6. Run the CleanAll target as follows.

   msbuild /nologo /target:CleanAll BuildBoost.proj
7. Have fun using Boost.

The magic is in the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props and Microsoft.Cpp.x64.user.props files, which are copied into *$(LOCALAPPDATA)\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0* by the CopyProps target. These props files are automatically imported by most, if not all project files. They set the AdditionalIncludeDirectories and AdditionalLibraryDirectories lists so that ICU and Boost will be found.